# read_table pandas python numeric error

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a basic `pd.read_table` of a `.txt` file.  The first column is a list of cusips.  The cusip `"65248E10"` is being read as a number `65248E10 = 652480000000000` (E10 as scientific notation).

I have been going through the pandas but I can't figure out how to require it to stay as a character.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_table

Also, even if I put header = 0, it seems to be putting the first row as the headers and then row 0 is the second row and so on.  If my text file has no column names, how can I get that to default to NULL (or 1, 2, 3, etc.)

Thanks for the help.  I am new to pandas/python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a data file which looks like

```
65248E10 11
55555E55 22
```

then we can read it in with something like

```
>>> pd.read_table("cusip.txt", header=None, delimiter=" ", converters={0: str})
          0   1
0  65248E10  11
1  55555E55  22
```

where we use `header=None` to tell it that there aren't any headers, we use `delimiter=" "` to tell it there's a space delimiter (adjust to match your data format), and `converters={0: str}` to tell it that after reading the first column in as a string, we want to turn it into a string (i.e. in this case do nothing to it) rather than process it further.  Instead of `converters={0: str}`, `dtype=(str, int)` would have worked too, but this way we can still let `pandas` figure out what the other columns are.

The problem with using `header=0` is that `0` here doesn't mean "no header", it means use row number #0 (the first row) as the headers.

Comment: One follow-up.  when header = None, I am getting my column name to default to X0 (which is fine).  However the converters is having a problem with it.  If I use converters={0: str} it says TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.  If I use '0' it doesn't work and 'X0' the same.  Any recommendation on this?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1911092: which version of `pandas` are you using?  `print pd.__version__`.

Comment: Okay.  First, I'd recommend upgrading -- a lot improved.  Second, I don't quite understand the error message -- that's the error message you'd get if `str` weren't the string type but an actual string.  Could you accidentally have rebound `str` to a string?  What does `print type(str), repr(str)` right before that line return?

Comment: You are right - I did call one of my strings above in my code str = "xxxxx"   Is this a faux pas in python?

Comment: @user1911092: yep. :^)  You can do it, rebind the builtins I mean ("shadowing", or sometimes "clobbering", it's called), but then after that you can't use them for anything else.  One of the most common Python comments on SO is "Don't call your integers `int`, your lists `list`, your dicts `dict`, your strings `str`, or your sums `sum`, etc.", for precisely the reason you've just come across -- then you can't use the builtins for anything else.  Plus names like `str` are often too generic to be self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

To stop your column from being read as a number, use the `converters` parameter and specify `str` as the converter for the column containing your "cusips".

For the header, as documented on the page you linked to, `header` is the *number* of the row which is to be considered the header; it is not a boolean saying "do I have a header or not.  Setting it to zero means to use row zero (i.e., the first row) as the header.  The documentation explicitly says:

> Specify None if there is no header row.